# Tailwindcss/CSS - How to ensure part of the layout (body height set 100vh) is scrollable with filling its parent?

Tags: css, scroll, grid, tailwind-css

I'm cloning Spotify as a practice project to learn tailwindcss and practice React.

Body element has fixed height using `width: 100vh` and `overflow: hidden` to hide overflowing elements. My general layout is a grid layout with 2 column and 2 rows. Looks like this:

```
|-------------|--------------|
|   sidebar   | main content |
|-------------|--------------|
| now-playing | now-playing  |
|-------------|--------------|
```

As you can see last element in grid layout is `now-playing` and it spans to two cells. My sidebar has an inner element which is for Library list where user's library items (playlists, artists, albums etc.) are listed. This element has no fixed height and I want it to always have 100% of left space and scrollable. At the moment, list overflows the body and is not scrollable. How can I ensure it fills the whole left space and is scrollable? (preferably using `overflow: auto;` so, if the list doesn't overflow scroll will not be visible.)

#### Current code:

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="h-screen bg-black p-2 text-white overflow-hidden">
    <!-- GRID LAYOUT START -->
    <div class="grid grid-rows-layout grid-cols-layout gap-2">
      <!-- SIDEBAR START -->
      <div class="h-full flex">
        <!-- NAVIGATION START -->
        <nav class="flex-auto flex flex-col gap-y-2">
          <!-- LINKS FOR HOME OR SEARCH PAGES START -->
          <div class="bg-card rounded-lg">
            ...
          </div>
          <!-- LINKS FOR HOME OR SEARCH PAGES END -->
          <!-- LIBRARY START -->
          <div class="bg-card rounded-lg flex-auto">
            <!-- LIBRARY FILTER AND ACTIONS START -->
            <div class="flex flex-col gap-y-4 px-4 py-2">
              ...
            </div>
            <!-- LIBRARY FILTER AND ACTIONS END -->
            <!-- LIBRARY LIST START -->
            <!-- HERE, I WANT BOTH "LIBRARY SEARCH AND SORT" AND "LIBRARY ACTUAL LIST"
                 ELEMENTS TO BE SCROLLABLE AND FILL THE PARENT ELEMENT -->
            <div class="min-h-full overflow-y-scroll px-2 pb-2">
              <!-- LIBRARY SEARCH AND SORT START -->
              <div class="flex justify-between pt-0.5 px-2">
                ...
              </div>
              <!-- LIBRARY SEARCH AND SORT END -->
              <!-- LIBRARY ACTUALY LIST START -->
              <div>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    ...
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    ...
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    ...
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <!-- LIBRARY ACTUAL LIST END -->
            </div>
            <!-- LIBRARY LIST END -->
          </div>
          <!-- LIBRARY END -->
        </nav>
        <!-- NAVIGATION END -->
        <div class="sidebar-resizer d-none"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="bg-card rounded-lg">Main</div>
      <div class="col-span-2">Now Playing</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Current output:

[image: Current output]

#### Desired output:

[image: Desired output]